# how to close a popup window when the user clicks on the main browser window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

```
chrome.windows.create(
{
  url: url.href,
  type: "popup",
  left: w,
  width: 500,
  height: 900
});
```

Im using this piece of code to launch a popup window on top of the main browser window. How do make it so that the popup window automatically closes if the user clicks off to the main browser window. Also I am using Manifest V3 for the extension.

```
chrome.windows.create(
{
  url: url.href,
  type: "popup",
  left: w,
  width: 500,
  height: 900
      
});

window.addEventListener("blur", function()
{
  window.close();
});
```

I tried to look for the "blur" event to automatically close the window, but this did not work.

Comment: The last block should be inside the script that runs in the window that you opened. The alternative is chrome.windows.onFocusChanged event in the main script.

Comment: what does the syntax look like for the block of code in the window instance? I tried adding it in there, but I kept getting errors. (just for clarification, the url for the popup page is a 3rd party website. I don't have access to it's code)

Comment: You can run a content script in that site, with the last block of code inside.

Comment: I tried using chrome.windows.onFocusChanged, but the window closes as soon as it opens. I posted the updated code below.

Comment: But you need to check which window became focused using the parameters of onFocusChanged listener, you can't just blindly do things.

Answer (score 0):

```
// gets resolution of the main window to open the popup in the right corner
  chrome.windows.getCurrent((cw) => {
    let w, h;
    
      w = cw.width - 500;
    
    // creates new popup window
    chrome.windows.create(
      
    {

      url: url.href,
      type: "popup",
      left: w,
      width: 500,
      height: 900,
      

    });

    // gets ID of the popup window
    chrome.windows.getCurrent((pop) => 
    {

      let popid = pop.id;
      
      // when focus changes the window closes
      chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener( (stat) =>
        {
          chrome.windows.remove(popid);
        });
    });
```

Tried this and it closes the window immediately as it opens.

Answer (score 0):

```
// All rights reserved to Isabella Rasku and Aditya Ponde 2023.

// making the context menu


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      id: "Lookup",
      title: "Lookup On RMP",
      type: 'normal',
      contexts: ['selection']
    });

});




// opens RMP when context menu is clicked with the search perms using selected text
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((item, tab) => {
  
  var name = item.selectionText;
  var uname = name.replace(/ /g, "+");
  let url = new URL("https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=teacherName&schoolName=&queryoption=HEADER&")
  url.searchParams.set('query', uname)

  // gets resolution of the main window to open the popup in the right corner
  chrome.windows.getCurrent((cw) => {
    let w, h;
    
      w = cw.width - 500;
    
    // creates new popup window
    chrome.windows.create(
      
    {

      url: url.href,
      type: "popup",
      left: w,
      width: 500,
      height: 900,
      

    });

    // gets ID of the popup window
    chrome.windows.getCurrent((pop) => 
    {

      let popid = pop.id;

      // when focus changes the window closes
      chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener( (stat) =>
        {
          chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener( (stat) =>
        {
          chrome.windows.remove(popid);
        });
        });
    });



  });

  

});
```

This works!